# showLabel in jqplot series

Tags: jqplot, legend, series

is there a way to not display a series label in the legend when label is entered in the series options (something like a showLabel:false) ?

Reason : I actually need a more explicit identifier that 1,2... to know which series I'm checking within a python script that will build the different buttons used to display or not some series.

Any help will by really appreciated.
If no such options is present for series I could just enter a brand new one option and fill it with the identifier anyway to perform the check in my python script afterward.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the showLabel option for each series. For example if you have 3 series and you want to not display the label of the second serie you can use something like the following :

```
series: [
 {showLabel: true},
 {showLabel: false},
 {showLabel: true}
]
```

Please see an example on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/Pm4yt/6/)

**Edit**

An alternative can be to define a variable with your own labels and to use it then in jqplot (example n°2 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/Pm4yt/7/):

```
 var mylabels = ["This", "particular", "way"];
 var plot = jQuery.jqplot('chart', [data], {...
  legend: {
   labels: mylabels
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped I wonder why though this option isn't displayed in the list on the jqplot official webpage.

Comment: Sorry to bother you Anthony but I updated my post on Vertical bands overlays with jqplot

Comment: I apologize to other users as this last issue is not related to the current asked question.